# VBA pasting row of data to another row with hidden column

Tags: excel, vba

As mentioned in title, I would like to ask if there is any simple VBA code for copying an entire row of data including all the formatting to another row  with hidden column (i.e. data at column N pasted to column N even it is hidden)?

Better without a loop to not slow down the runtime of VBA.

I just used `EntireRow.Copy` before and find that it messes up the table.

Comment: If you want to copy entire row with all the formatting, you'd need to unhide the column and re-hide it afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Range.Copy method along with the PasteSpecial method. Here's a simple code:

```
Sub CopyHiddenColumns()
    Dim sourceRow As Range
    Dim targetRow As Range
    
    ' Change to your source and target row
    Set sourceRow = ActiveSheet.Rows(2)
    Set targetRow = ActiveSheet.Rows(20)

    sourceRow.Copy

    ' Paste the data and formatting including hidden columns
    targetRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```